# Porque ocorre o Illegal invocation no JS?

Tags: javascript, golang

Estou usando o GopherJS, e nele existe duas formas de executar uma função, via `Call()` ou via `Invoke()`. Inicialmente estava usando um código similar a este:

```
js.Global.Get("navigator").Get("credentials").Get("store").Invoke(
    password.New(js.M{"id": id, "password": pass, "name": email}),
)
```

Mas, tinha como resultado:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'store' on
>   'CredentialsContainer': Illegal invocation
>       at :1:36

Então, resolvi testar o `Call`, usando `js.Global.Get("navigator").Get("credentials").Call("store", ...)`, isso funcionou, mas fiquei curioso porque o o `Invoke` não funcionou.

---

No Javascript, parece que tem um comportamento similar se fizer:

```
x = window.navigator.credentials.store; 
x(new PasswordCredential({id: "a", password:"b"}))
```

Ou, ainda se fizer:

```
window.navigator.credentials.store.call(
    new PasswordCredential({id: "a", password:"b"})
)
```

Em ambos os casos resulta no erro de `Illegal invocation`.

---

Porque esse erro ocorre? Porque só ocorre com algumas funções/objetos? Há como identificar se há como usar o `Invoke` (ou, o `Call` do Javascript?) antes de causar o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Go: `store` é o método, então precisamos usar `Call`. `Invoke` funciona apenas em funções. Existe uma diferença, veja abaixo.

Em JS: um método não é como uma função normal, pois tem `this`. Você pode usar um método como uma função assim:

```js
// Não funciona.
x = window.document.querySelector;
elem = x("a");
// Funciona, observe o bind().
x = window.document.querySelector.bind(window.document);
elem = x("a");
// Também funciona.
x = window.document.querySelector;
elem = x.call(window.document, "a");
```

Links de documentação:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call